# Source not found on Vagrant up

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, sh, file-not-found

I have the below code in my `Vagrantfile` which calls the below script. The script runs fine up until the last line `source $dotfile`. When it gets to `source`, the script says `source: not found`. The line before, `cat $dotfile` works just fine so the file clearly exists.

Why is this file somehow not found for the `source` command but it works for the previous `cat` command?

`output error`

```
==> default: /vagrant/scripts/create_functions_dotfile.sh: 14: /vagrant/scripts/create_functions_dotfile.sh: source: not found
```

`Vagrantfile`

```
config.vm.provision "#{script["name"]}", type: "shell" do |shell|
  shell.inline = "/bin/sh /vagrant/scripts/create_functions_dotfile.sh"
end
```

`scripts/create_functions_dotfile.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

dotfile=/home/vagrant/.functions.sh

for file in /vagrant/scripts/functions/*; do
  echo "cat $file >> $dotfile"
  cat $file >> $dotfile
done

echo "source $dotfile" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
cat $dotfile
source $dotfile
```

Comment: WRT a suggested edit that changed code in an answer, [suggested reading](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266479/1677912).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Source is specific for #!/bin/bash, so either you

1. substitute

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   ```

   with

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ```
2. substitute

   ```
   source $dotfile
   ```

   with

   ```
   . $dotfile
   ```

---

ETA: as a matter of fact, the error complains that 'source' is not found, not its argument.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you. I'd used `sh` because I thought I'd read that `sh` was more portable and would automatically point to `bash`.